# How to Show modal popup in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I need to show details on the popup. I don't have any idea how to do this. I need to do it in a MVC3 Razor view.

my Controller-

```
public ViewResult ViewDetail(Int32 id)
{
  var q = from p in db.accs
          where p.id == id
          select p;
  return View(q.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

my View-

```
<td>@ Html.ActionLink("View Detail", "ViewDetail", new { id=item.id }) </td>
```

Comment: I tried to use jquery but still popup is not visible.

Comment: You can use window.open for pop up. refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911134/mvc-3-razor-popup-window

Comment: @Renuka Do you want to open it on click of button or something , please post some code as to what you tried , we will get a better idea.

Comment: I dont want to use input button.i am using Html.ActionLink(). Anyway thanks.

Comment: @Bhumika I think she is not talking about popup window , its normal popup.I might be wrong.

Comment: @freebird Yes may be!! I think if she just want to use popup and don't want to do any jquery stuff then better to use popup window.

Comment: I want to show  popup not popup window.I need to show my edit,insert and deatil views in popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Jquery UI [ModalForm](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) to show up your data.

Say you want to display the following in Modal pop-up of jquery .

```
<div id="displayinmodal">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" id="submitdata" value="Upload" />
</div>
```

Now write your jquery like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#displayinmodal").dialog({ //displayinmodal is the id of the div you want to display in modal popup
         autoOpen: true
     });
});
</script>
```

That's it. you should get Modal popup in your browser.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This kind of task isn't really what ASP.NET MVC / Razor does.  Consider using a Javascript library like [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  You have to add several of the JQuery UI scripts to your page, but the payoff is a very simple API; you can create a basic dialog out of any HTML element (say with id *mydiv*) with one line of code:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).dialog();
```

And of course there are customizations and themes you can apply.

Of course, you could simply use the Javascript:

```
alert("my details here");
```

to get a basic modal popup, but I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple no frills modal (with not much content) you can use a JavaScript alert like so:

```
alert('Hello from a modal popup');
```

If you would like a prettier option a common solution is to use jQuery UI's dialog which allows for a modal option. Take a look here for a demo of what you get with this option:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

The code is pretty simple; the below should do everything for you using Google's CDN as a source for the scripts and stock jQuery UI CSS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#details" ).dialog({
            modal: true
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="details">
    Hello from a modal popup
</div>
```